# PySide: Place/move animated QMovie GIF in QSplashScreen

Tags: animation, pyside, gif

I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I'd like to be able to place an animated GIF in a specific spot on my QSplashScreen.

The GIF has to be animated using multiprocessing and the onNextFrame method so that it will play during the initial load (otherwise it just freezes on the first frame).

I've tried inserting self.move(500,500) everywhere but nothing is working (well not working well enough).  Right now, the GIF will play in the spot I want, but then it will snap back to screen center on the next frame, then back to the spot I want, etc.  Inserting the move method every possible place hasn't fixed this issue.

Here's the code:

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')
        self.move(500,500)
class MySplashScreen(QtGui.QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, animation, flags):
        # run event dispatching in another thread
        QtGui.QSplashScreen.__init__(self, QtGui.QPixmap(), flags)
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(animation)
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.onNextFrame)
        #self.connect(self.movie, SIGNAL('frameChanged(int)'), SLOT('onNextFrame()'))
        self.movie.start()
        self.move(500, 500)

    def onNextFrame(self):

        pixmap = self.movie.currentPixmap()
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())
        self.move(500, 500)

# Put your initialization code here
def longInitialization(arg):
    time.sleep(args)
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, time

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and display the splash screen
#   splash_pix = QPixmap('a.gif')
    splash = MySplashScreen('S:\_Studio\_ASSETS\Tutorials\Maya\Coding\Python\_PySide\GIF\dragonGif.gif',
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
#   splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    #splash.raise_()
    splash.move(500, 500)
    splash.show()

    # this event loop is needed for dispatching of Qt events
    initLoop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(longInitialization, [2], callback=lambda exitCode: initLoop.exit(exitCode))
    initLoop.exec_()

    form = Form()
    form.show()
    splash.finish(form)
    app.exec_()
```